# How to decrypt an Apple Server-To-Server notification using PHP

Tags: php, encryption, jwt, webhooks

I have been struggling with this subject for several days now. I am not sure whether [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/app_store_server_notifications_v2) is bad or the lack of code examples is the one thing that complicates everything. I am also surprised that it would seem almost no one is using it as I wasn't able to find good examples online.

I did the following process:

1. I added a sandbox webhook in App Information and I am running it via ngrok (tunnel) to check the information I receive.
2. After a while I was able to figure out what exactly I had to base64 url decode from the response and I ended up with an object with this structure.

```php
Array
(
    [headers] => stdClass Object
        (
            [alg] => ES256
            [x5c] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ...,
                    [1] => ...,
                    [2] => ...,
                )

        )

    [payload] => stdClass Object
        (
            [notificationType] => DID_RENEW
            [notificationUUID] => ...uuid...
            [data] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [bundleId] => ...app.id...
                    [bundleVersion] => 1.5
                    [environment] => Sandbox
                    [signedTransactionInfo] => ... //long string of encrypted info
                )

            [version] => 2.0
            [signedDate] => 1670890743027
        )

    [signature] => ... // signature string
)
```

I have reduced the fields because of size, but it's basically as follows according to the docs:

- `headers->alg` - is the algorithm used
- `headers->x5c` - is an array of 3 keys

Citing Apple's Docs

> The App Store signs transaction and renewal
> information that you receive in App Store Server Notifications V2 and
> in the App Store Server API. It uses the following x5c certificate
> chain, in order:
>
> 1. A certificate that contains the public key that corresponds to the key
>    the App Store uses to digitally sign the JWS.
> 2. An Apple intermediate certificate from the Apple PKI site that starts with Worldwide Developer Relations.
> 3. An Apple root certificate.

After that:

- `payload` is an object that contains the relevant information, the one being relevante here would be

`payload->data->signedTransactionInfo`

And last there's the

- `signature` property which I am not sure what to do with.

From what I understand I need to decrypt a JWT using the keys given in the response. I tried using [this PHP library](https://web-token.spomky-labs.com/), but I am not sure how to proceed. The data is very different and I am not sure what's the correspondence. I only know that it uses ES256, but not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a relatively old question but I recently stumbled across your post searching for a solution myself. At the last WWDC 2023, Apple released official libraries that make the App Store Server API and Server Notifications easy to use. Unfortunately, there are only libraries for Swift, Node.js, Python and Java. As I use PHP myself and have to use Apple‘s APIs, I decided to translate the official libraries into PHP. You can find my implementation here: https://github.com/hoels/app-store-server-library-php

Hope that helps in case you are still looking for a solution.

Comment: Woah, cool @hoelska, unfortunately I am no longer working on this project, but will keep this in mind :)